# Cognos 10, run.prompt=false, prompt page still appear

Tags: php, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a php page that will fill value to parameter on the URL.
ie: you must set the years, choose the country, and choose the product code.

In the report studio, I have set the required values for the years only. The other values are optional.

What I have learned about passing parameters through URL is simple.

> http://server:port/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognos.cgi?b_action=cognosViewer&run.outputFormat=HTML&ui.object=storeID("put my StoreID here")&ui.action=run&cv.header=false&cv.toolbar=false&**run.prompt=false**&p_year1=2016&p_year2=2017&p_others_parameter=param_values&CAMUsername=public&CAMPassword=public

The value is placed as expected. The store ID is directing me to the right report.

My problem is why the prompt page is still appear?
Is there a properties that I need to set again?

Comment: How have you defined the prompts as optional? There are two places this can be done: 1. The filter 2. The prompt control. If you configure the prompt control as optional but then use the parameter in a required prompt OR within a data item itself, Cognos will treat it as a required prompt and ignore the Required property on the prompt.

Comment: No, I haven't defined the prompts as optional, because those report is still in used by another application with the prompt page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Johnsonium, I came to this conclusion.
I have some parameter, they are p_year, p_country, and so on in my cognos report studio..
Reffering to this link [How do you pass parameter values to reports inside a Cognos Workspace dashboard via URL?](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21996204)
I have realize, that **p_** is a must in the URL.
For my problem, I have set the parameter names as I mentioned above.
And why the prompt page still appear?, **because the cognos can't catch all the expected parameters**.
And why the cognos can't catch all the expected parameters?, **because I miss to put p_ in my URL.**
So how to solve my problem is to put **p_** in my URL before my parameter name.
p_p_year instead just p_year
p_(WhateverYourParameterNameWas)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you may be using a parameter which has no default value